# Unblock Google Analytics on all company computers except a few users

Tags: tracking, web-filtering, traffic-filtering, google-analytics

We are currently blocking GA in our company using IP filtering. We all share the same IP so exclude this in GA.

However, we have an internal sales team that take sales on the phone. We'd like GA to be able to track these users. How can I allow GA to track hits from just a few computers?

We're thinking of giving them their own landing page with unique UTM parameters, bu obvious with the IP filtering this won't show up. We tried a VPN but for some reason this isn't working. Any ideas people?

Comment: If you mean Sophos UTM, you can set up filtering groups. WebAdmin/Web Protection/application control

Comment: Are you excluding getting an additional IP and putting just those people on it.? That is easy with the right firewall.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, different UTM. This one stands for “Urchin Tracking Module”; it’s a URL query parameter used by web analytics tools like Google Analytics.

Comment: @DanielK We tested this with a few free VPN platforms. We cleared caches and cookies, then accessed the site. GA didn't appear to be picking up our visits. Really strange that it should still be blocked.